# Semi transparent textures look different on different android phones

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparency, textures

I'm using opengl, pretty new to it. Tried rendering a semi transparent cloud in my app recently but it looked different on my Galaxy S and my HTC desire HD :(.

Here is an image of the clouds on both phones [clouds on Galaxy S and Desire HD](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/clouds.png/).

Been reading around for ages, it seemed like Bitmap.config had smthng to do with the problem, so i added this line just before my bitmaps are loaded:

```
mBitmapOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
```

There was no difference. Really appreciate any tips, thanks!

Edit:

I've added the following two lines in my onCreate method but the texture remains the same on both phones.

```
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
```

Edit:

I've tried drawing the same image using the api demos static sprite activity to rule out mistakes in my code but got the same problem.

Edit:

Also tried drawing the same texture on a HTC Sensation and a LG Optimus 2x. Same problem on the HTC Sensation as on the Desire HD, no problems on the LG Optimus 2x.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling dithering by caling `gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DITHER)` (or the equivalent of the gl version you are using if not GL10).

Edit: and if that don't work, also call `getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);` in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Thanks for responding, i've tried enabling dither, just tried again, doesn't rectify the problem.

Comment: Hi i've tried adding that as well as getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);. No effect for both.

Comment: Strange, then I don't know what might be causing the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097887/bitmaps-on-ics-are-loaded-with-wrong-pixel-format) may be related to yours. Perhaps, you're running unofficial build on HTC Desire HD.

Also try following settings (call it in your `Activity.onCreate(..)` method):

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
```

Comment: Doesn't change the texture, i'm using the official build anyway