# How to take a good quality screenshot on emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I don't have a tablet but I wanted to take screenshots from the emulator for display in Google Play. I did that using Eclipse (using the method given in the top answer here [How to take emulator screenshots using Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065993/how-to-take-emulator-screenshots-using-eclipse)) but the screenshots are not good quality: the image is broken (some areas are kind of shifted) in at least one spot each time I take a screenshot.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: try deleting the avd and create a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13685844/2910492) answer that is an emulator issue. To solve this, you need to enable the 'use host GPU' setting when creating an emulator, according to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17166234/2910492) answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) shipped with ADT (also listed as Debug monitor) and choose the device and app, then click that camera icon. It creates very good looking screenshots.

I also got some rendering errors with the emulator... It's best with actual devices. You can also try if other images/[emulators](http://www.genymotion.com/) perform better.

Comment: That's what I did but it had problems described.

Comment: Download GenyMotion Software you will have the real device effect for android emulator

Comment: Not sure, on the real device I took screenshots using other methods (I have Samsung galaxy and take screenshots by pressing home and power). That works well.

Comment: @Szymon: Try the emulator I linked to. Even though it requires registration (what for?) and is a bit slower than the ADT emulator for me, it got some cool features. It's worth a try!