# How to correctly configure pixel formats of Window / SurfaceView / Opengl-surface on Android

Tags: android

In my android app I use following APIs:

A) Window.setFormat(PixelFormat)
B) SurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat)
C) OpenGL: EGL10.eglCreateWindowSurface(...)

To correctly use/understand those APIs I need to find answers to following questions (question 4 is most important to me):

1. What are supported values for A) and B) on each device model - do they depend on android API version only or one have to query some other API in runtime to find this out?
2. What are default values when A) and B) is not called at all? Do they depend on android API version only or one have to query some other API in runtime?
3. Does A) and B) fails (how such error is reported) when not supported value is passed or android safely downgrades to lower quality format (how to find out when that happens)?
4. What dependencies have to be met between A), B) and C) for application to work correctly?

Information I found so far:

2
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097887/bitmaps-on-ics-are-loaded-with-wrong-pixel-format) claims that for Window.format default value is
RGB888 for android 2.3 and higher
RGB565 for older devices
Also there's Display.getPixelFormat() method that was deprecated (in android api level 17) and now always returns RGBA_8888

4
I assumed that Surface.format must always match OpenGl.format. However I found out that setting SurfaceView-format == RGB_565 and OpenGl-format == RGBA_8888 works correctly on my Nexus7.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this option (into AndroidManifest.xml) in order to avoid the default RGB_565:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```